# Trying to understand Angular error message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-controller

I am trying to solve a problem happening when injecting an element to a customer website that uses Angular framework.

Edit: Sorry, the page uses Angular (also called Angular2) not just AngularJS.
Sorry about the mistake.

The error message we`re seeing is this:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=SomoController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Does anyone know in which situations is this error message displayed?

Appreciate it,

Thanks

Edit:
Adding some more information, the website, the Controller and the Angular part of the code are not mine. The application is added to the website by a script the website owner adds to their website.

This error only shows up when the application is on the page. When it is not, the page works as expected.
One more thing is that this message pops up whenever a link on the website is clicked.

Edit: Other messages that only show up when the problem occurs are:

```
xdomain (http://someaddress.com) socket: [object Object]
xdomain (http://someaddress.com) socket: null   
xdomain (http://currentwebpageaddress.something.something.net): failed to parse absolute url: app/modules/somecontrollerfunctionality/index.htm
```

There is also receive socket, send socket and close socket.

Do this messages have something to do with the problem?

Hope all that helps more.
Much appreciated, everyone.

Comment: When something isn't defined or present. In this case, looks like `SomeController` is unknown, so either it's not included in the code you're trying to use or not properly imported etc.

Comment: Can we have a bit more of information? like your controller code, your app.js.

Comment: Have a look at the DI syntax: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: This could be due to many reasons. You might find this useful: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq

Comment: @lealceldeiro That's what the OP linked to.

Comment: @DevMoutarde The controller code is not mine. It is from the customer website, so I don't have access to it. My application is loaded to the page via a script that the customer adds to its page. I'll add some more information to the question

Comment: @Donal I will take a look at that and see if there is anything that can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Are you injecting your part using decorators?

Comment: @DevMoutarde No. The javascript code injects the HTML onto the website and loads the other files that will do the other functionalities.

Comment: Ok. Well anyway, it seems that your controller isn't recognize as Dave Newton said.. see if you didn't make any typo.. its hard to tell indeed, with so little info :/

Comment: Ok, i will try doing that.
Is there any way that new HTML elements being added to the page cause the controller to not be recognized?

Comment: IMO (but I'm still just 'getting started' in the angular world sooo I may be mistaken) it shouldn't have anything to do with any html element, at least not like this. I was able to reproduce the same error yesterday but it was indeed just a typo, my controller wasn't being detected because of that aha.. I think you first have to make sure that 'somoController as you called it, is actually defined ! if it is, you may be able to take a closer look at whats going on here...

Comment: If you are calling an <div ng-app="yourAppName">  in your code, make sure you didn't make any typo on that as well ! (yes here basically its pure html code ahah but it has a deeper link to the controller than just HTML markups if you get what I mean... )